# Migration fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I ran sevreal migration on my production sever (add table Subscription, Rename a table Stat to Order) but then I enconter a problem.
I don't know what to do to fix the problem. Here my error message in rails console:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "subscriptions" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"subscriptions"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"subscriptions"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Edit: I already make rake db:migrate
Edit 2: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0963ec46f079699a56a0 (here my schema.rb)
Edit 3: My application is host on Alwaysdata and i already restart it

Comment: what does your schema.rb look like pre migration, what does the migration look like that is causing this error?  are you using symbols for you table names in the migration or strings?

Comment: Restarting your app after migrations is recommended to pick up the table changes: Try `heroku restart`.

Comment: Did you run `rake db:migrate` on the server with `heroku run rake db:migrate`? Maybe you just stripped the heroku syntax in front?

Comment: I edit my post.
Doon: ou right i run all migration at once i ll make it step by step to identify wich one is causing the problem

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution my bad:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```